# UPnPを用いて、ファイヤーウォールをバイパスする手法

Tags: network, security

UPnPを少し調べると、脆弱性が存在していることがわかりました。

ddos用のボットネット構築に用いられたり、スパムメール配信やワンクリック詐欺など,,,,,

その中でファイヤーウォールを回避することも可能という記事を見つけました。

[UPnProxy: Blackhat Proxies via NAT Injections](https://www.akamai.com/site/en/documents/research-paper/upnproxy-blackhat-proxies-via-nat-injections-white-paper.pdf)

4ぺージにfirewallの回避方法があったのですが、いまいち理解できません。

理由としては、ルータにファイヤーウォールを設けていたら、どのポートを外部のアドレスとマッピングしても、ルータ内を通過するためファイヤーウォールを回避したことにならないのでは？と思ってしまうためです。

根本的に考え方が間違っていると思うので、解説の方をよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 解説も何も机上の空論は虚しく、ご自身でUPnPを操作してみればはっきりすることでは？

Comment: 実際に操作しました。
xmlファイル取得まではできましたが、僕が持っている機器では脆弱性を確認できなかったので、NATの情報をインジェクションするところまではできなかったです。